# accent character replaced by \xed in python/django

Tags: python, json, django, format, diacritics

I got a response from server in format json, but when I show that in the htmltemplate the accents are changed by \xed. (django framework)

If I use the `json.dumps` the result is perfect, but when then I can't acces in the template like a dictionary.

```
json.dumps(json_received_from_server, ensure_ascii=False)
```

And I wonder, ok let's convert the unicode from `json.dumps` to dict by `ast.literal_eval` but it raise an error (malformat string ).

I tried `json.loads(json_received)` and didn't work too.

How can I show properly this accents in my django template?

Thx.

Answer (score 2):

When dealing with extended range characters in Django and Python 2.7, you should be aware that there are two types of strings: unicode and byte strings. You should try and keep your strings as unicode and let Django's template rendering engines deal with converting it. You can tell if your data is unicode with print, there will be a "u" prepended to the string value ...

```python
# byte strings
print "mañana"          # => "mañana"

# unicode strings
print u"mañana"         # => u"mañana"
```

Make sure your strings stay unicode, modifying strings with non unicode strings will force Python to encode and turn it into a byte string. Avoid similar situations to the examples below by making sure your string liberals are prefixed with "u", like this:

```python
"Hello" + u" World"     # => "Hello World"
u"Hello" + u" World"    # => u"Hello World"

u"Hello %s" % "World"   # => "Hello World"
u"Hello %s" % u"World"  # => u"Hello World"
```

So go through your code that is problematic and make sure the strings your dealing with stay unicode, using print to verify that they do indeed stay unicode.

Comment: That `print unicode("mañana")` is a really bad idea. That will only happen to work is `sys.getdefaultencoding()` is the same as your source file encoding. On most setups, that's not true, so `print unicode("mañana")` will just give you a `UnicodeDecodeError`. In fact, you should _never_ call `unicode` on a string without an explicit codec_it's the same as the situations you suggest avoiding below.

Comment: Thanks for the extra details @abarnert. I am assuming that prepending the "u" to a string is not problematic, and only the unicode() function requires an explicit codec.

Comment: The `u` prefix on string literals is fine–but you need to make sure you've specified a source encoding on your source file.

Comment: Since the original question pertains to Django, which automatically does the final encoding in its rendering engine, the question asker doesn't need to worry about specifying a source encoding.

Comment: Though, the question asker should make sure that their Django project's settings don't override the default encoding, using latin1 or something equally limited can cause problems.